# Run a For Each Loop from the selected value (instead of starting from the first one) at a validation list in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, validation, foreach

I am trying to ask the Macro to start running the Loop from the "active" value of the validation list as with the current code shown below, each time i run the macro starts from the first value of the list. Thanks!

```
Dim dvCell As Range
 Dim inputRange As Range
 Dim c As Range
 Dim i As Long


 'Which cell has data validation
 Set dvCell = Worksheets("ValperSIS").Range("e20")
 'Determine where validation comes from
 Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)


 i = 1
 'Begin our loop
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In inputRange
 dvCell = c.Value

    If Range("CHECKSIS") = False Then
    Exit For
    End If
```

'Loop[Copy-paste workbooks]
    Next c

Answer (score 0):

You can use Match to get the starting point:

```
'Which cell has data validation
Set dvCell = Worksheets("ValperSIS").Range("e20")
'Determine where validation comes from
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

m = Application.Match(dvCell.Value, inputRange, 0) '<< start position
If not iserror(m) then
    for i = m to inputRange.cells.count
        dvCell.Value = inputRange.cells(i).Value
        'etc
        'etc
    next i
End If
```